# Why do I get a "Detached Head" message when I perform the Checkout revision and Commit operation in Android Studio 3.3.1?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I use GitHub in my project in Android Studio 3.3.1.

A: I edit a file two times, and Commit then Push the project two times, it's OK. you see the image Step 1.

B: I hope to return the point "Submit 1", so I perform the *Checkout Revision* operation just like the image Step 2.

C: Checkout Revision operation is success, and I get image Step 3, but I find Git display *5adce2b8* on the bottom-right corner of the image Step 3, I don't understand why it doesn't display *master*.

D: I make some modify, but I get the error "Detached Head" just like the image Step 4 when I perform Commit operation, why ? how can I fix it?

**Step 1**
[image]

**Step 2**
[image]

**Step 3**
[image]

**Step 4**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you checkout a revision by id or a tag, you are asking git to set your working tree there *but* without a branch attached to follow you when you decide to do any operation... which is fine by git, no problem at all. This status is called `detached HEAD`. If you ask git to commit, for example, git will create a new revision, set the previous revision as its parent, everything just the way it normally goes... the difference is that, because you weren't working on a branch, there's no branch pointer to move to set on this new revision that you just created. Again, this is perfectly normal from the point of view of git. Now, for you as a developer, this is *not* the way you would like to work *normally*. If you want to do development work like a new feature, say, you probably want to be able to commit and then jump anywhere at any time and not to have to see the reflog to be able to see where you had left your work hanging... that's why you would use a branch to develop your feature.

But them, what is detached HEAD used for? I can quickly think of these situations:

- Need to checkout a remote branch and I actually don't need or want a local branch for it (won't do any development there, just check something and then go back to where I was)
- Need to test that a merge is going to go fine before I move the real branches involved
- Need to do a quick fix by pulling a change from a branch into another branch that is on a remote.

And people will think of other dozens reasons to work on detached HEAD. It's one of the wonders of git, actually.

If you had done the checkout on a terminal, you would get a big warning from git telling you about starting to work on detached HEAD and also would give a few instructions to get out of it. Normally, you just create a branch where you are and check it out. It can be done in a single shot:

```
git checkout -b some-new-branch
```

And you would be working on a branch again, no more detached HEAD state.

Answer (score 2):

Basically "DETACHED HEAD" means that you're not on a branch. If you want to not just check out the state of the repo at that point but continue to work on it, you're gonna want to set (reset) a branch there, so "Reset the current branch to here".

Checkout revision – set your working directory to match the files at that point.
Revert – cancel the changes introduced by that commit (will create a revert commit).

I'd recommend reading [git branch basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell). Everything about git should begin to make sense after you do that.